# multithreading with fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

> ```
> private  ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
>
>    {
>         GetFullSessionFactoryFor(sessionFactoryConfigPath);
>         while (!sessionFactoryReady) Thread.Sleep(1000);
>         return (ISessionFactory)sessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath];
>  }
>
>
>  private void GetFullSessionFactory(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
>     {       
>    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
>          {
>            ISessionFactory sessionFactory=null;
>            FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = fluentConfiguration.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("sessionfactoryname","somevalue"))
>                                          .Mappings(m =>
>                                          {
>                                              m.FluentMappings
>                                                  .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("nameofassembly"))
>                                                  .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always(),
>                                                                   OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.All()),
>                                                                   DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue(),
>                                                                   DynamicInsert.AlwaysFalse(),
>                                                                   DefaultCascade.None()
>                                                                  )
>                                                  .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<"SomeConvention">();
>                                          }
>                                                   );
>
>          sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
>
>           });
> }
> ```

I am creating minisession factory on main thread(not shown here) and full session factory on second thread.
The problem is when it hits buildsessionfactory the code never returns back.Am i doing it right?

```
public class NHibernateBaseDAO<T>
{
    public NHibernateBaseDAO(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, int sessionId)
    {


        SessionFactoryConfigPath = sessionFactoryConfigPath;
        SessionId = sessionId;
    public bool Save(T entity)
    {
        bool saveSuccessful = true;
        try
        {
            NHibernateSession.Save(entity);
        }
        catch (NHibernate.HibernateException)
        {
            saveSuccessful = false;
        }
        return saveSuccessful;
    }

    public bool SaveOrUpdate(T entity)
    {
        bool saveSuccessful = true;
        try
        {
            NHibernateSession.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
        }
        catch (NHibernate.HibernateException)
        {
            saveSuccessful = false;
        }
        return saveSuccessful;
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        NHibernateSession.Delete(entity);

    }

    public void CommitChanges()
    {
        if (NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.HasOpenTransactionOn(SessionFactoryConfigPath, this.SessionId))
        {
            NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSessionFrom(SessionFactoryConfigPath, this.SessionId).Flush();
            NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.CommitTransactionOn(SessionFactoryConfigPath, this.SessionId);
        }
        else
        {
            NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSessionFrom(SessionFactoryConfigPath, this.SessionId).Flush();
        }
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.BeginTransactionOn(SessionFactoryConfigPath, this.SessionId);
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.RollbackTransactionOn(SessionFactoryConfigPath, this.SessionId);
    }

    public bool IsDirty()
    {
        return NHibernateSession.IsDirty();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query() {
        return (IQueryable<T>)NHibernateSession.Query<T>(); 

    }
    protected ISession NHibernateSession
    {
        get
        {
            return NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSessionFrom(SessionFactoryConfigPath, this.SessionId);
        }
    }


    protected readonly string SessionFactoryConfigPath;
    protected int SessionId;

    protected System.Data.IDbConnection DbConnection
    {
        get { return NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetDbConnection(SessionFactoryConfigPath, this.SessionId); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a list of object arrays. use this for general queries
    /// </summary>
    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetSqlQuery(string queryString, IList<Criterion> criterion, Type returnType)
    {
        queryString += CriteriaToSql(criterion);

        return NHibernateSession.CreateQuery(queryString).Enumerable();
    }

    protected ICriteria AddCriteria(IList<Criterion> criterion)
    {
        ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(persistentType);

        foreach (Criterion criterium in criterion)
        {
            switch (criterium.Comparison)
            {
                case SqlComparison.StartsWith:
                    criteria.Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(criterium.Property, criterium.Value1.ToString(), MatchMode.Start));
                    break;

                case SqlComparison.Contains:
                    criteria.Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(criterium.Property, criterium.Value1.ToString(), MatchMode.Anywhere));
                    break;

                case SqlComparison.Equals:
                    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(criterium.Property, criterium.Value1));
                    break;

                case SqlComparison.Between:
                    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Between(criterium.Property, criterium.Value1, criterium.Value2));
                    break;
                case SqlComparison.MoreThan:
                    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Gt(criterium.Property, criterium.Value1));
                    break;
                case SqlComparison.LessThan:
                    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Lt(criterium.Property, criterium.Value2));
                    break;
                case SqlComparison.InList:
                    criteria.Add(Restrictions.In(criterium.Property, (System.Collections.IList)criterium.Value1));
                    break;

            }
        }
        return criteria;
    }
    protected string CriteriaToSql(IList<Criterion> criterion)
    {

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get delimiter for data, defaults to ' unless specifed for data type
    /// </summary>
    protected string[] GetDelimiter(object value)
    {

}
public class Criterion
{
    public Criterion(string property, SqlComparison comparison, object value1)
    {
        Property = property;
        Comparison = comparison;
        Value1 = value1;
    }
    public Criterion(string property, SqlComparison comparison, object value1, object value2)
    {
        Property = property;
        Comparison = comparison;
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
    }
    public Criterion(string property, SqlComparison comparison, object value1, bool not)
    {
        Property = property;
        Comparison = comparison;
        Value1 = value1;
        Not = not;
    }
    public Criterion(string property, SqlComparison comparison, object value1, object value2, bool not)
    {
        Property = property;
        Comparison = comparison;
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
        Not = not;
    }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public bool Not { get; set; }
    public SqlComparison Comparison { get; set; }
    public object Value1 { get; set; }
    public object Value2 { get; set; }
}
public enum SqlComparison { StartsWith, Contains, Equals, Between, MoreThan, LessThan,   InList }
 }
```

one last question please. I am using generic class to access sessionfactory so i cannot explicitly access the minisession. with this how do i access minisession based only  on certain entities if the full session is not available and full session factory when it is available.

Answer (score 1):

you never set sessionfactoryready to true

Update: a more complete example.

```
void Main()
{
    Database.InitRealFactoryAsync("<sessionFactoryConfigPath>");

    var minifactory = Database.GetMiniFactory("<sessionFactoryConfigPath>");

    // Do some stuff with minifactory

    var realsessionfactory = Database.SessionFactory;

    // Do stuff with real factory
}

static class Database
{
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void InitRealFactoryAsync(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
            sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("nameofassembly"))
                    .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always(),
                        OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.All()),
                        DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue(),
                        DynamicInsert.AlwaysFalse(),
                        DefaultCascade.None())
                    .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<FoxproDateConvention>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        });
    }

    public ISessionFactory GetMiniFactory(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.Load("nameofassembly");
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add(assembly.GetTypes().Where(Filter).ToArray())
                .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always(),
                    OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.All()),
                    DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue(),
                    DynamicInsert.AlwaysFalse(),
                    DefaultCascade.None())
                .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<FoxproDateConvention>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get {
            while (sessionFactory == null) Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

UpdateUpdate:

```
void Main()
{
    Database.InitRealFactoryAsync("<sessionFactoryConfigPath>");
    Database.InitMiniFactory("<sessionFactoryConfigPath>");

    using (var session = Database.GetSession(true))
    {
        // Do some stuff where minifactory is enough
    }

    using (var session = Database.GetSession())
    {
        // Do stuff with real factory
    }
    ...
}

// class Database
public ISession GetSession()
{
    return GetSession(false);
}

public ISession GetSession(bool miniFactoryIsEnough)
{
    if (realSessionfactory != null)
        return realSessionfactory.OpenSession();
    if (miniFactoryIsEnough)
        return miniSessionfactory.OpenSession();
    else
    {
        while (realSessionFactory == null) Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return realSessionfactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Update: "access minisession based only on certain entities"

you need to specify the type you want to use in the session:

```
public ISession GetSession(Type persistentType)
{
    if (fullSessionfactory != null)
        return realSessionfactory.OpenSession();
    if (miniFactory.GetClassMetadata(persistentType) != null)
        return miniSessionfactory.OpenSession();
    else
    {
        // minifactory doesnt contain the type needed, wait for full factory
        while (fullSessionFactory == null) Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return fullSessionfactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

some additional advice

**do not `catch (NHibernate.HibernateException)`**

- you lose valuable information and the calling code can't really decide what to do when false is returned
- session state is inconsistent see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1819150/671619

FlushMode should be `Flushmode.Commit` and `public void CommitChanges()` can be written as

```
var session = NHibernateSession;
if (session.Transaction.IsActiv)
{
    session.Transaction.Commit();
}
```

cut out the whole sessionId stuff as it seems to provide no value. hold the session instead of sessionId instead

Comment: Can someone help me why the thread never returns back after builsessionfactory realsessionfactory above

Comment: i don't believe that buildsessionfactory never returns, it is most probably GetSessionfactory(). Plz try my code in a simple console app to see how it could be done

Comment: It work when i change the nameofassembly into something else for testing but not with the one it should be working. when i remove the thread it works fine. i mean the sessionfactory is never created.

Comment: in the code you posted the sessionfactory is assigned to a _local_ variable which is thrown away immediatly. There is no sign where the sf is put into `sessionFactories` neither where the sessionFactoryReady is set to true. and also whats the point in starting another thread and wait until it finishes? See my code to see where the thread is started and when the result is used

Comment: Actaully the logic behind this is to used minisession factory and wait for fullsessionfactory until it is ready

Comment: Can you give me your mail Id please. i desperately need your help

Comment: sorry but i can't give extensiv support, i have work on my own. I am willing to help you on Stackoverflow. If you have problems you are free to ask questions on SO and there are a lot of people who can help you.

Comment: could you please check above i have added a class NHibernateBaseDAO<T>. one last question please. I am using generic class to access sessionfactory so i cannot explicitly access the minisession. with this how do i access minisession based only on certain entities if the full session is not available and full session factory when it is available.